# Set of Integers, find expectation of twin pairs (defined in description)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Consider the set S of integers from 1 to N. Any two integers $1 ≤ a ≤ b ≤ N$ are called a twin pair if they are exactly a distance two apart, i.e., $b − a = 2$. For example, $(1, 3),(2, 4),(5, 7). . .$ are examples of a twin pair. Suppose one chooses a random subset of size $N/4$ from $S$ with all outcomes being equally likely. What is the expected number of twin pairs. You can assume that $N$ is a multiple of $4$

I attempted to solve this using linearity of expectation but couldn't calculate the generalized probability for a set with $N$ numbers

Comment: Well, enumerate the twin pairs.  How many are there?  For each pair, what is the probability that both elements are in the random subset?

Comment: Linearity of expectation is indeed a useful tool for a correct approach.  Let us count how many twin pairs there are in our set by breaking it down by a sequence of yes/no questions... "Are 1 and 3 both in the set?"  "Are 2 and 4 both in the set?"  "Are 3 and 5 both in the set?"... "Are N-2 and N both in the set?"

Comment: As for how to find the probability that  a specific pair is used... for example the probability that both $1$ and $3$ appear in our set... [the hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) can handle that nicely, or you can derive the formula yourself using counting methods.

Comment: The expected number of twin pairs needs to be in terms of N, I know how to calculate it for distinct N values (N=4,8,12...)

Comment: And.... so.... what is stopping you from being able to generalize to arbitrary values of $N$?  Don't be startled by the fact that we don't know what number $N$ is currently representing... it can still be used in arithmetic and algebraic simplifications just like any other number can be.

Comment: Its the generalization where calculating distinct values has a lot of simplification and going from the probability for the general case to the expecatation for the general case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from the comments:

Let us assume that $N$ is a positive multiple of $4$, i.e. let us set $N=4k$ with $k\in\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.

Let $X$ be the random variable counting the total number of "twinpairs."

For each $i$, let $\chi_i$ be the binary random variable $\chi_i=\begin{cases}1&\text{if both}~i~\text{and}~i+2~\text{are included in our selection}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Recognize how $X$ relates to our collection of $\chi_i$'s

> $X=\chi_1+\chi_2+\dots+\chi_{(N-2)}$

Let us look at calculating probabilities associated with each of the $\chi_i$'s.  The probability $Pr(\chi_1=1)$ for example is the probability that both $1$ and $3$ are included in our selection.  Using counting methods or using [the hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) leads us to:

> $Pr(\chi_1=1)=\dfrac{\binom{4k-2}{k-2}}{\binom{4k}{k}}=\dfrac{\frac{(4k-2)!}{(k-2)!(3k)!}}{\frac{(4k)!}{k!(3k)!}}=\dots$

$~$

> $\dots = \dfrac{k!(4k-2)!}{(k-2)!(4k)!}=\dfrac{k(k-1)}{4k(4k-1)}$

The same logic and calculations leads us to the calculation of $Pr(\chi_i=1)$ for each $i\in\{1,2,3,\dots,N-2\}$

Knowing $Pr(\chi_i=1)$ allows us to calculate $E[\chi_i]$.

Combining all of this knowledge leads us to being able to calculate $E[X]$

Comment: Thanks so much! I found my mistake, I was double counting when doing the expectations.